# When I use f.write to write string, it only writes numbers/codes

Tags: python

I have a simple piece of code to write a bunch of strings to file:

```
    data = self.measure()
    f = open('output.txt', 'w')
    print data
    for line in data:
        print 'line:', line, type(line)
        f.write(str(line))
    f.close()
```

But this gives me an output file looking like:

```
0034 0045 1056
0086 9078 0567...
```

I thought my data was in unicode or something, so I tried a few things like changing to this:

```
f.write(unicode(line))
```

Which resulted in the same file output
However when I use this:

```
f.write(str(line) + ';' + unicode(line))
```

I get the correct and expected text in the file:

> hal_init() for chip version 0x02c4;hal_init() for chip version
>   0x02c4ram_prog, ed_list=  [edata(0x50000, 0x517c1)];ram_prog, ed_list=
>   [edata(0x50000, 0x517c1)];Summary:;Summary:==== ....... etc

I dont understand why, or what I am doing wrong. Clearly I am missing something about the format/type of the variable 'line'. But type(line) just tells me its a string...

Can anyone explain?

Comment: use `print(line, file=f)`

Comment: What were you expecting? What does self.measure() return?

Comment: @SzabolcsDombi Invalid syntax error, Im using python 2.6.6

Comment: 2.6.6 bad for you

Comment: @JonClements I expect a list of strings in 'data', and this is what I see when I print it to the terminal, and use type() to test it.

Comment: This is certainly strange, and the data you put on your question looks ok, but you need to post a [mcve] that exhibits this behaviour so we can reproduce it on our machines. (FWIW, I normally use Python 3.6.0 these days, but I also have Python 2.6.6 installed).

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

SublimeText 3 encoded the output file as hexadecimal. There are a few hex values inside the string which I guess it spots and trys to be clever with the encoding... Blah

Not sure why the f.write(str(line) + ';' + unicode(line)) code made ST3 encode it different...

Thanks